# Deleting a value from a field of model in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on basic ecommerce website in django.I am having the following view that checks for a successful order.

```
def handlerequest(request, id):
    order=Order.objects.get(id=id)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.save()
            print('order successful')
        else:
            order.dstatus="Cancelled"
            order.save()
            
            
    return render(request, 'handlerequest.html', {'response': response_dict,'order':order})
```

The **items** here refer to the products that a user has chosen to buy.My product models is as below with size model.(I have removed some fields)

```
class Siz(models.Model):
    size=models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    size=models.ManyToManyField(Siz)
```

What I have done is that in my siz model I have added several sizes(eg. S,L,M) and for product I have selected the sizes which are available for each product. Now my concern is that whenever someone orders something then after checking in the view that the order is successful , I want to remove the size of the item ordered from the product.(For Example if someone orders a product AB of size L then from available size of that product I want to remove L)
The following is my orderitem and order model for reference.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,)
    size=models.ForeignKey(Siz,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

I also want to keep in mind that if there are multiple items that a user orders then the sizes that are ordered should be removed for all products . I tried working around it but nothing worked for me. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `OrderItem` has a specific `Size` associated with it (the ForeignKey), I assume that a single order cannot contain multiple sizes (so, it can have multiple products of same size, but not multiple products of various size). If that's the case, I suggest changing the model a bit so that you keep track of how many Products you've got available:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size=models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ProductItem(models.Model): # the "warehouse", ie how many we've got available
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product)
    size=models.ForeignKey(Size)
    quantity=models.IntegerField() # how many still available


class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,)
    size=models.ForeignKey(Size,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField() # how many within a single
```

Notice the `quantity` property, both within the `OrderItem` (how many ordered) and `ProductItem` (how many still available). This way you could easily keep track of how many products you got left.

I think that such [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship isn't really correct in this context, as the `Size` table is some sort of enumeration - you'll add, let's say, 10 various sizes there and should never touch that table again, right? Great example of many-to-many relationship is a `Book` and `Author`, because there'll be multiple Books by multiple Authors and none of this objects is, in general, an "enumeration" or something with finite set of "possible values". In the end, `Size` itself does not really *belong* to any `Product`, right?

Comment: I already have a stock field in product model(which I didnt find relevant to show in the question). Your solution would help in tracking the quantity available with me but that is not what I wanted. Firstly for example a product has 5 different sizes available and one person orders that product of one size say 's' then I want that the size s from that product is removed so that if another person sees that product only 4 sizes are visible for him to order

Comment: Then you filter it out on UI - you simply check that for this ProductID and SizeID, Quantity is 0, so it's currently not available. What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes but still I have to remove sizes which are ordered and are not available further

Comment: But you'd still filter it in the UI rather than in DB, that for this particular product a particular size is not available because Quantity is 0.